Can't capture a drop event in an ng flowchart angular
The problem is when I drag and drop one of the nodes from the palette in the canvas grid and I just want to capture this event but nothing displays in the console=>not captured.
This is for the callback:
constructor(private stepRegistry: NgFlowchartStepRegistry) {
    this.callbacks = {
      onDrop: this.onDrop.bind(this),};}

This is the Drop method:
onDrop(event: NgFlowchart.DropEvent) {
    console.log('Dropped:', event.step.type, event.step.data);
    // Handle dropped item here
  }

And this is the template:
<div id="canvas" ngFlowchartCanvas [ngFlowchartOptions]="options" [ngFlowchartCallbacks]="callbacks"
  [disabled]="disabled">
</div>

I tried to capture the event but nothing was displayed in the console

After giving the docs a brief read, I have noticed it's got two methods for handling drop events:

onDropError?: (drop: DropError) => void; Called whenever a new step
fails to drop on the canvas.
onDropStep?: (drop: DropEvent) => void; Called whenever a new step or existing step is successfully dropped on the canvas.

I think you need to change your callback event name from this.callback.onDrop to this.callback.onDropStep.
So change this.callbacks = {onDrop: this.onDrop.bind(this),};} to this.callbacks = {onDropStep: this.onDrop.bind(this),};}
